# Entity Framework fails to load child classes (Eager Loading)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am following a course on Udemy on .NET Core 3.1 MVC.  I have run into an issue with eager loading.

When loading the `Service` class, we also need to load the related  `Category`, and `Frequency` classes as well.  But that's not working.

I should note that the course instructor had all of his Key's called just `Id`, which is a practice I don't prefer. So I called them `ServiceId`, `CategoryId`, and `FrequencyId` instead. I suspect this (might?) be the root of the problem. But if so, I can't find where to fix it.

This is the SQL being created by EF. Note the lack of an joins.

```
SELECT [s].[ServiceId], [s].[CategoryId], [s].[FrequencyId], [s].[ImageUrl], [s].[LongDesc], [s].[Name], [s].[Price]
FROM [Service] AS [s]
```

Here are the classes in question, stripped to just what is needed for this question:

```
    public class Service
    {
        [Key]
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Serivce Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Frequency")]
        public int FrequencyId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FrequencyId")]
        public Frequency Frequency { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Category Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Display Order")]
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Frequency
    {
        [Key]
        public int FrequencyId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int FrequencyCount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Frequency Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in the controller:

```
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    var data = _unitOfWork.Service.GetAll(includeProperties: "Category,Frequency");
    return Json(new { data });
}
```

And `GetAll()` where `dbSet` is `DbSet<Service>`

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = null)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
    if (filter != null)
       query = query.Where(filter);

    // includeProperties will be comma seperated
    if (includeProperties != null)
    {
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
           query.Include(includeProperty);  // <--- THIS IS WHERE THE EAGER LOADING SHOULD HAPPEN
        }
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
        return orderBy(query).ToList();

    return query.ToList();
}
```

I get back all of the records from the `Service` table, but what I don't get back is any of the related `Category` or `Frequency` classes. They are just null.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the result of calling `Include`:

```
foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
   query = query.Include(includeProperty);  
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is the answer.

Comment: glad it worked! I did this before, that's why I immediately thought about it!